# How do I modify the translate3d value and another properties using javascript?

Tags: javascript

When an event occurs, I want to change the value as shown in the code below.

The coordinate values of the translate3d property are modified, and the cubic-bezier values are added.

How do I do it with only javascript and no css?

### before

```
style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);"
```

### after

```
style="transform: translate3d(-1265px, 0px, 0px); transition: transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s;">
```

### structure

```
<div class="item-container" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
     <div id="tv-plus-gallery-item-1" data-analytics-gallery-item-id="Tv Plus Gallery item 1" data-ac-gallery-item=""
class="gallery-item theme-dark current" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tv-plus-gallery-item-1-trigger"
style="--progress:0; z-index: 1; opacity: 1; transform: translate(0px, 0px);">
<!-- ... -->
</div>
     <div id="tv-plus-gallery-item-2" data-analytics-gallery-item-id="Tv Plus Gallery item 2" data-ac-gallery-item=""
class="gallery-item theme-dark" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="tv-plus-gallery-item-2-trigger"
data-original-aria-hidden="" aria-hidden="true"
style="--progress:1; z-index: 0; opacity: 1; transform: translate(1265px, 0px);">
<!-- ... -->
</div>
```

I want to implement a slider whose value changes depending on the event.

I don't want to use jquery etc.

Comment: Get the element, for which you want to change the properties with [`document.getElementById()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) and then change the values through the style property.

Comment: @Geshode document.getElementsByClassName('item-container'); doesn't work?

Comment: First, there are no elements with the class name `item-container` in your provided code. Second, I said, you could use getElementById to get an element through its id.

Comment: @Geshode The example code has been modified. Please confirm.

Answer (score 0):

`getElementsByClassName()` returns an array, so you need to access the individual element, if you want to change its style.

```
const containers = document.getElementsByClassName('item-container')
const firstContainer = containers[0]
firstContainer.style.transform = 'translate3d(-1265px, 0px, 0px)'
firstContainer.style.transition = 'transform 1s cubic-bezier(0.645, 0.045, 0.355, 1) 0s'
```

This way you can change the style of the element using Javascript.